# failed to build: failed to fetch builder image in argo using paketo

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argo-workflows, argo, paketo

I am trying to build image using argo and paketo but I am getting this error

```
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base': Cannot connect to the Docker
daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
time="2023-08-25T12:39:48 UTC" level=info msg="sub-process exited" argo=true error="<nil>"
```

Here is my code

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: paketo-demo-
spec:
  entrypoint: run-tasks
  templates:
    - name: run-tasks
      steps:
        - - name: git-clone
            template: git-clone
        - - name: build-and-push
            template: build-and-push

    - name: git-clone
      container:
        image: alpine/git
        args: ["clone", "https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/samples", "/workspace"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workspace
            mountPath: /workspace

    - name: build-and-push
      container:
        image: buildpacksio/pack
        args: [
          "build", "paketo-demo",
          "--builder", "paketobuildpacks/builder:base"
        ]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workspace
            mountPath: /workspace
          - name: pack-cache
            mountPath: /pack-cache

  volumes:
    - name: workspace
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: pack-cache
      emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: did u figure this out ? im wondering whether it is viable to build images in argo, or should we generally use jenkins and/or tekton+paketo

Comment: @Sandeep I did not go on with packeto. I am using kpack